# No application encryption key has been specified. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I run my unit tests unsing Laravel I have an error that I can't resolve...

```
No application encryption key has been specified.
```

I've tried this twice commands:

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache
```

Nothing changes there, I always remain blocked whereas my key exists in the .env...

I also tried to delete the .env and regenerate one from the .env.example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel's embeded PHPUnit uses `.env.testing` file to load dotenv variables and also has an option to override dotenv variables by specifying on `phpunit.xml`.

Try create the file `.env.testing` and input test-dedicated env variables and make sure you have `APP_KEY` entry on it.

For more details, see this link; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/testing#environment